# Is it possible to lengthen a Vietnam tourist visa from six months to one year inside Vietnam?

Tags: thailand, vietnam, visa-extensions, cambodia, laos

Assuming I get a six months tourist visa to Vietnam (either by *visa on arrival* or directly from consulate) and I reached to Vietnam and already spent there almost six months and need to spend six more months.

### My problem

Because, originally, I could have one year instead six months (if I would have paid a larger visa fee), I assume and I might be wrong that there should be a way to extend the six months visa inside Vietnam, to get extra six months;
Thus, in such case I wouldn't have to go to another country and then comeback for another six months.

### My question

Is it possible to lengthen a Vietnam tourist visa from six months to one year inside Vietnam?

Comment: It was definitely possible to extend a on-month tourist visa for a second month five or six years ago. In fact my hostel in Da Lat took care of it for me for less than the price I was expecting if I'd gone myself to the immigration office in the big city. But six and twelve months sounds like it might be less easy.